# Rotation gesture changing view frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

What I want to achieve: I want to create a copy of selected view. 
I have two `UIImageViews` on `UIView`. I am selecting both the views and want to clone both the views.

Everything is working fine until I am not rotating the `UIImageView`. If am rotating the view `UIImageView` changing its frame.

```
UIView *viewClone = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(fltLeadingMin, fltTopMin, fltCloneViewWidth, fltCloneViewHeight)];
viewClone.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[viewClone addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

for (UIImageView *imgView in arrSelectedViews) {

    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imgView];
    UIImageView *imgViewClone = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];

    imgViewClone.frame = CGRectMake(imgViewClone.frame.origin.x - viewClone.frame.origin.x, imgViewClone.frame.origin.y - viewClone.frame.origin.y, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
    imgViewClone.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;

    [viewClone addSubview:imgViewClone];
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After rotating the image, its frame won't work anymore and that's the reason for your issue.

You can take a look at [Apple document for UIView's transform property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform?language=objc)

> When the value of this property is anything other than the identity transform, the value in the frame property is undefined and should be ignored.

The solution for this situation is using `center` and `transform` properties instead of `frame`.

```
UIView *viewClone = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(fltLeadingMin, fltTopMin, fltCloneViewWidth, fltCloneViewHeight)];
viewClone.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[viewClone addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

for (UIImageView *imgView in arrSelectedViews) {

    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:imgView];
    UIImageView *imgViewClone = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];

    // This is the frame before you rotate image, can be replace with another size
    CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    imgViewClone.frame = originalFrame 

    // Using center and transform instead of current frame
    imgViewClone.center = imgView.center;
    imgViewClone.transform = imgView.transform;

    imgViewClone.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;

    [viewClone addSubview:imgViewClone];
}
```